# Multiple regexps on perl command-line doesn't work as expected

Tags: regex, perl, command-line, multiline

I am using two regexp expressions in a perl command-line, but it doesn't give the expected result:

```
$ cat test
foo
bar
#baz
#haz
naz
$ perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/g; s/\\n#.*$/CHEESE/' test
foo\nbar\n#baz\n#haz\nnaz\n\n
```

I would expect the result to be `foo\nbarCHEESE`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your input file is being read one line at a time; the code is executed once for each line of input. Because the newline character is at the *end* of each line, the second regex pattern `\\n#.*$` can never match

The solution is to enable *slurp* mode which fetches the whole file in a single read. Then your subsitutions will happen only once. A switch value of `-0777` will do this for you

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/\n/\\n/g; s/\\n#.*$/CHEESE/' test
```

#### output

```
foo\nbarCHEESE
```

Comment: Can you share the reference for difference types of switch values in perl?

Comment: @mkHun: You can read the documentation that came with Perl by using `perldoc perlrun` or the same information is on line [here](https://p3rl.org/perlrun)